# How to I get Paypal payments to trigger confirmation emails that exist already

Tags: php, html, paypal, payment-gateway

The website already accepts payment, and send you your details once the payment has been made.

How can I do this with paypal? I know how to add a paypal button, but how do I link it with my website to trigger the confirmation email once the payment has been processed through paypal?

Comment: if, you have a pay confirmation page that loads when the payment is confirmed, just add an argument like; get the user details at the confirmation page and then add your email sending argument.

Comment: you should take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry i offended you, was just asking a question some may find easy to answer unlike myself.

Answer (score 0):

When submitting the form to PayPal insert another input with the name of `return` where the PayPal should return when a successful payment has been done.

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="www.yourwebsite.com/payment-done">
```

Give a link to your website and then you can send the confirmation email to the client through your server.

Example:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller@designerfotos.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="hat">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="15.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="www.yourwebsite.com/payment-done">
</form>
```

---

There are several variables that you can use;

- `return` - *The URL to which PayPal redirects buyers' browser after they complete their payments.*
- `rm` - *Return method. The FORM METHOD used to send data to the URL specified by the return variable.*
- `cancel_return` - *A URL to which PayPal redirects the buyers' browsers if they cancel checkout before completing their payments.*

---

Read more;

- [PayPal Checkout Page Variables - PayPal Developer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#paypal-checkout-page-variables)
- [HTML Form Basics - PayPal Developer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/)